# Get images from wordpress post (post content)

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to get the first image of the post in wordpress.
I have various posts. So for new posts, I can set the featured image. However there are thousands of old posts. I need to extract the first image from those posts so that I can use them to display.

I used the code from http://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/get-the-first-image-from-a-post/ and I dont think its working for me.

```
global $post;
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'category' => 6 );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post);
......
.....
endforeach;
```

I need to display the image from each post lets say as in a gallery in the form of thumbnails. I searched a lot but could not figure out how.

Answer (score 4):

Put this in your `functions.php`

```
function getTheFirstImage() {
    $files = get_children('post_parent='.get_the_ID().'&post_type=attachment&post_mime_type=image');
    if($files) :
        $keys = array_reverse(array_keys($files));
        $j=0; $num = $keys[$j];
        $image=wp_get_attachment_image($num, 'large', false);
        $imagepieces = explode('"', $image);
        $imagepath = $imagepieces[1];
        $thumb=wp_get_attachment_thumb_url($num);
        echo "<img src='$thumb' class='thumbnail' />";
    endif;
}
```

Then use in your template `getTheFirstImage()` function where you want to print the image

```
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'category' => 6 );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post);
    getTheFirstImage(); // Will print the image
    ......
    .....
endforeach;
```

[Check this forum post](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/function-to-get-first-image-associated-with-current-post).

Comment: What about for a single post. Say I want to get the image for a post whose ID is known to me.
`$post->ID=12` And now I want the image in the post_content for this post

Comment: Then just pass the id `$files = get_children('post_parent=2&post_type=attachment&post_mime_type=image');`

Comment: @Heera : How can't get a full size image please ?

Comment: Remove `class=thumbnail` from `<img src='$thumb' class='thumbnail' ./>`.