# WordPress - Get ID of First Image in Post Content

Tags: php, wordpress, image, posts

As a new designer I am new to use of underlying Wordpress functions. I am learning. I have a requirement to reproduce components of the posts we have written which requires me to  extract certain aspect of the WP Post Object for re use. I have made progress understanding the use of 'get_post' / 'get attachment' and related functions but am stuck after a couple of days trying to extract the image_id for the first image in the post content. So for example when I run this snippet

```
        $data = get_posts( array(
       'post_type'   => 'post',
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'post_status' => null
       
    ) );
```

I get the array full of post data. An extract of one post in the array below

```
[2]=>
object(WP_Post)#4039 (24) {
["ID"]=>
int(3013)
["post_author"]=>
string(1) "1"
["post_date"]=>
string(19) "2021-01-16 07:14:08"
["post_date_gmt"]=>
string(19) "2021-01-16 07:14:08"
["post_content"]=>
string(1367) "


        FIRST IMAGE FROM MEDIA (How do i get its ID or URL for re-use)
        (PLUS SOME WORDS)

"
["post_title"]=>
string(16) "1.Another Star"
["post_excerpt"]=>
string(0) ""
["post_status"]=>
string(7) "publish"
["comment_status"]=>
string(4) "open"
["ping_status"]=>
string(4) "open"
["post_password"]=>
string(0) ""
["post_name"]=>
string(16) "1-another-star"
["to_ping"]=>
string(0) ""
["pinged"]=>
string(0) ""
["post_modified"]=>
string(19) "2021-01-17 19:32:36"
["post_modified_gmt"]=>
string(19) "2021-01-17 19:32:36"
["post_content_filtered"]=>
string(0) ""
["post_parent"]=>
int(0)
["guid"]=>
string(26) "http://example.com/?p=3013"
["menu_order"]=>
int(0)
["post_type"]=>
string(4) "post"
["post_mime_type"]=>
string(0) ""
["comment_count"]=>
string(1) "0"
["filter"]=>
string(3) "raw"
}
```

My question is how i can programatically get the id of the image rendered in 'post content' so I can use it elsewhere. I have tried running queries like

```
     $attachments = get_posts( array(
     'post_type'   => 'attachment',
      'numberposts' => -1,
      'post_status' => null
    ) );
```

which gives me the data for attachments in my media folder but that doesn't say which posts the media is attached too. So ive come at it from both angles trying to get something that gives me an image_id from the post_id. Or vice versa.

Im sure this is all down to my novice stature with this stuff. So would really appreciate any steer. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Are you trying to get the "featured image" ID, or the id of an image that only appears in the content, e.g. an image that was added in the WYSIWYG? And where are you trying to use the image once you get it? There might be a better way to approach this.

Comment: Aww...thank you for the welcome. Two days of trying and finally realised help was needed. Its not a featured image. Its an image uploaded to each post (content) using the Gutentor image uploader

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get images from wordpress post (post content)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17353100/get-images-from-wordpress-post-post-content)

Comment: Sadly not really. I looked at that page before posting. It seems a bit out of date. It relies on adding a new function to the themes folder. Surely to simply get the image id or url for an image attached to  the post content does not rely on all that?

Comment: Is the image embedded in the gutenberg editor as an "Image" or an "Inline Image". The methods for extracting the first image are completely different depending.  The difference is that one is a standalone "block" while the other injects HTML into another block (e.g. a paragraph block)

Comment: Im using the Gutentor Element (block) . The orange image uploader. Does that help answer that question. It has no options other than to upload?